# Problema ao montar TextViews no Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Eu estou criando um projeto em Android Studio, a visualização não ficou como eu esperava e gostaria de saber onde errei.

Aqui esta o XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


 <TextView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Calculadora"/>


   <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Digite o Primeiro Numero"/>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android.id="@+calculo/numero1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Digite o Segundo Numero"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android.id="@+calculo/numero2"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android.id="@+botao/btsoma"
    android:text="somar"/>



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android.id="@+calculo/resultado"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

A visualização era para ficar parecida com essa:

[image]

Mas o resultado é que somente apareceu o nome calculadora.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Quando a orientação não é especificada, por omissão assume **horizontal** e neste caso deve ser **vertical**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
...
```